# Android ListView cell with dynamic background colour and Selector

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, background, selector

I have a populated list view with different backgrounds depending on what category that item is in, all set in the `getView()` method of the view's adapter. Problem I have is that doing that hides the selector.

I've come across a nice fix for this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> 
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> 
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> 
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@color/some_color" /> 
</selector>
```

This works but would mean that I would have to make one for each category, seems like a lot of redundant code to me. Is there a way I can use this colour selector but to set the `state_selected="false"` dynamically in code?

Answer (score 1):

Your ListView comes with any adapter. whether it is array adapter or by extending base adapter. we set adapter to list view. our view is managed by that adapter. so go to that adapter. because you have to give some condition. i gave my codition that if position is 2 then `view.setSelected(false)` . Also you can set background color as disable to that view here.